# Calculate a cumulative sum columwise with a specified number of columns

Tags: r, cumsum

below you can see an example of a larger table I have

```
library(data.table)
input  <- data.table(ID     = c("A", "B"),
                     Para   = c(2.8, 5),
                     Value1 = c(50, 80),
                     Value2 = c(80, 40),
                     Value3 = c(80, 100),
                     Value4 = c(60, 10),
                     Value5 = c(40, 80))
```

What I want to achieve is to add a column with the cumulative sum of the next x columns specified in the Para column. But if there is digit after the comma it the value in the column should be adjusted by the digit.

So for the first row (Para = 2.8) the result should be

```
1*50 + 1*80 + 0.8*80 = 194
```

the result for the second row (Para = 5) should be

```
1*80 + 1*40 + 1*100 + 1*10 + 1*80 = 310
```

The final table should look like

```
output <- cbind(input, Result = c(194, 310))
```

What I thought about is split the Para value 2.8 into a percentage vector of 5 numbers, so the whole range.

```
c(1, 1, .8, 0, 0)
```

multiply the columns Value1:Value5 with this vector and then sum up all Value1:Value5. But I don´t know how to split 2.8 into such a vector and maybe there is a better solution I am not aware about. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution which keeps the data in wide format and use `Reduce()` to compute the "weighted row sums":

```
library(data.table)
input[, Cumul := {
  tmp <- c(rep(1, Para), Para %% 1)
  mul <- replace(rep(0, ncol(.SD)), seq_along(tmp), tmp)
  Reduce(sum, .SD * mul)
}, .SDcols = Value1:Value5, by = ID]
input[]
```

> ```
>    ID Para Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Cumul
> 1:  A  2.8     50     80     80     60     40   194
> 2:  B  5.0     80     40    100     10     80   310
> ```

This will work for an arbitrary number of columns specified by `.SDcols` or if `Para` is larger.

Comment: Maybe `.SDcols = names(input)[-(1:2)]` to automatically consider all columns after `ID` and `Para` ?. This assumes that those 2 columns always come first and then there's a a series of Value columns...

Comment: @AntoniosK In general, I feel safer to specify the columns I want to work on (in case another column is being added you have to remember to update your code in another place). Here, in the given example we can write even shorter `.SDcols = -Para` as `ID` is already excluded through `by = ID`

Comment: Impressive! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo division `%/%` and the remaining rest of the division to create the multipling vectore and then use everything for example in an `apply`-call:

```
apply(input, MARGIN = 1, function(x) {
  multiplier <- as.numeric(x["Para"])
  multiplier_long <- c(rep(1, multiplier %/% 1), multiplier %% 1)[1:5]
  multiplier_long[is.na(multiplier_long)] <- 0
  sum(as.numeric(x[-c(1, 2)]) * multiplier_long)
})

# [1] 194 310
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
input  <- data.frame(ID     = c("A", "B"),
                     Para   = c(2.8, 5),
                     Value1 = c(50, 80),
                     Value2 = c(80, 40),
                     Value3 = c(80, 100),
                     Value4 = c(60, 10),
                     Value5 = c(40, 80))

library(tidyverse)

# function that creates a vector of multipliers based on Para column
# assumes that you have ID, Para and rest columns are Value 1,2...,N
# if Para is larger than the corresponding values it keeps first x multipliers
f_create_vector = function(x) {
    y = if(x %% 1 > 0) c(rep(1, x), x %% 1) else rep(1, x)
    z = rep(0, ncol(input)-2)
    c(y, z[-seq_along(y)])[1:(ncol(input)-2)] 
}


input %>%
  group_by(ID, Para) %>%                              # for each combination
  nest() %>%                                          # nest data
  group_by(ID) %>%                                    # for each ID
  mutate(vec = list(f_create_vector(Para))) %>%       # create a column of multipliers in a list
  mutate(CumSum = map2(data, vec, ~sum(.x * .y))) %>% # get the cumsum using multipliers and the value columns
  ungroup() %>%                                       # forget the grouping
  unnest(data, CumSum) %>%                            # unnest those columns
  select(-vec)                                        # remove that column

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   ID     Para CumSum Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5
#   <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A       2.8    194     50     80     80     60     40
# 2 B       5      310     80     40    100     10     80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split `Para` into a 5-valued vector, you cna try something like:

```
input %>%
  select(ID,Para) %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 5)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(Para = if_else( (Para - rn)>0, 1.0, 
                        if_else(Para - rn > -1, Para - lag(rn), 0))) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

which gives:

```
   ID     Para
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     1    
 2 A     1    
 3 A     0.800
 4 A     0    
 5 A     0    
 6 B     1    
 7 B     1    
 8 B     1    
 9 B     1    
10 B     1
```